# How to get into this fork() statement

Tags: c, fork

I am having such trouble figuring out how this piece of code works -

`if(fork()||!fork())`

I know the first fork creates a child for the initial process, and !fork() creates a child for the previous child. But for which process do we enter the if condition? If I was wrong earlier, please correct me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to understand this is to convert the `||` expression to separate `if` statements that implement the short-circuiting.

```
if (fork()) {
    // This is the parent process
    /* body */
} else {
    // This is the child process
    if (!fork()) {
        // This is the grandchild process
        /* body */
    }
}
```

Where `/* body *` is whatever was in the body of the original `if` statement.

Since `fork()` returns non-zero in the parent process, the body is executed in the parent after creating the first child, and in the grandchild.

Comment: That's a lot clearer than my answer :-D

Comment: I started trying to write an answer like yours, but I got myself all confused trying to describe it. So I switched to this.

Comment: Yeah, i'll leave mine up just if there's someone who likes getting tangled up in the if's and but's the way I did :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(fork()||!fork()) /* statement */
```

1. The first `fork` executes and *if* it returns a child `pid_t` the condition becomes `true` and the second condition is **not** evaluated because of [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and the following statement is executed.
2. if the first `fork` returns `0`, it's the child process and the second condition is evaluated.

   - If the second `fork()` returns `0` (that is, it's the child process) the full expression becomes `true` and the following statement is executed.